# How do I use the returned value from jquery load and a variable value in the callback function the same jquery load?

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to capture the current value of a variable and a loaded value (from jquery.load) to use in a callback function after the load process.

```
$container.load(itemURL, function(myVariable) { 
// do stuff with myVariable and $container.text()
} )
```